# magento 2: error braintree on refund - Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, creditmemo, refund, braintree

I have this error on Magento 2.3.3 when I try to refund (credit memo) an order with braintree.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in vendor/magento/module-braintree/Gateway/Validator/ErrorCodeProvider.php on line 41
```

I did some research, but I didn't find nothing so far. I need your help!

Answer (score 0):

this error happened for me when the transaction was not settled. I turned on the Braintree debug setting and received a more descriptive error to that one above!

'message' => 'Cannot refund transaction unless it is settled.',

Comment: Oh I gotcha, it make sense. So, this basically means that the transaction went through, but the money has not been collected in the account and so the refund cannot be done?

Comment: Yes you need to check in braintree the status of the transaction. I think this will be "unsettled" which magento doesn't recognise, hence the error.